# having issue while attaching/Uploading Email using IMAP in Outlook Web in MailBox(Drafts Folder)

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, imap

I am trying to upload an email in my Drafts MailBox Folder and need to edit first then send it to where i want. 
I am using C# language for this, and i am using an opensource library named "Ae.Net" https://www.nuget.org/packages/AE.Net.Mail/

and finally i have done with the uploading but there is an issue that i want you guys to help me please.

Issue is, when i upload an email into drafts folder, its get uneditable.
i am not able to edit it.
why is that?

[This Image shows what i am trying to say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjNlh.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `MSGFLAG_UNSENT` flag was erased while importing/uploading emails. The [PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessageflags-canonical-property) property contains flags according to which the item is displayed in Outlook. I'd suggest contacting a library developer for that.

Comment: It's an open source library, i do have a source code. If you tell me the method where i need to do, i'll do it sir.

Comment: please help, i am waiting!